# Parse Query Parameters

Tags: code-golf, parsing

The challenge is this:

You are given a url that is as follows:

`http://sub.example.com/some/dir/file.php?action=delete&file=test.foo&strict=true`

There can be either `http` or `https`, there can be any number of subdomains or directories, and the end file can have any name.

You are to create a full program (that can be compiled/interpreted) that when given a key will return the correct value and if no key is found it will return an empty string.

For example:

```
> https://example.com/index.php?action=delete
...> get(action) #=> delete
> https://this.example.com/cat/index.php?action=delete
...> get(action) #=> delete
> http://example.com, https://action.example.com/actionscript/action.jpg
...> get(action) #=> none
> https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2
...> get(action) #=> 2
```

There are no language restrictions and score is calculated a 1 point for every byte. Smallest score wins.

To clarify:

- You do not need to handle URL encoding
- The script only needs to run once and produce a result
- The script can take any input form: STDIN, Prompt, even passed as a function argument

Example:

Javascript, <s>101</s> 105 bytes

```js
function p(k){var m;return((m=location.href.match(new RegExp('.*[&\?]'+k+'=([^&]*).*')))!==null?m[1]:'');}
```

Comment: What about URL encoding? If I recall correctly there are at least two different RFCs on that, which are not compatible. Should we support URL encoding at all, and if so, in which form?

Comment: You do not need to support URL encoding, the only thing you have to do is get the value of the key encoded or not.

Comment: Does the program need to run in an input/output loop and keep producing  results, or can it just read a URL and a key on STDIN and produce the result once?

Comment: Once is all that is needed.

Comment: Can we assume that the given input will be a valid query key? Or could it contain `&` or `=` as well? (In which case we'd always return an empty string.)

Comment: You can assume that the query will always be valid.

Comment: Your example wouldn't actually work. Input keys `action` `ction` and `n` would all return `delete`.

Comment: I think this question needs more test cases. Could you please add the expected results for each of the following URLs (all with query key `action`): `http://example.com`, `https://action.example.com/actionscript/action.jpg`, `https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2`

Comment: Fixed at the cost of 4 bytes.

Comment: Can we assume that the path doesn't contain ampersands and the query string doesn't contain additional question marks? Your example code seems to do that.

Comment: You can assume that the url will look exactly like the four examples above.

Comment: Still fuzzy: it's not clear where the url is from. In your JS example you use the current document url, that is of no use for other languages AND not easy even in JS for testing

Comment: My example focuses purely on the browser (as it's all I have). My example doesn't necessarily have to translate to other languages but is to sort of show what I want achieved. As for testing you just pop it in the JS console and use p() to query the key.

Comment: I've often seen parameters duplicated such as `https://www.google.com/search?q=foo&q=foobar` (search google, change the query in the input box, search again, note the value of the URL) - how should `http://example.com/foo.cgi?action=foo&action=bar` be handled?

Comment: You only need to return a value, for the purpose of this challenge the only thing you have to work with is the four urls above.

Comment: What is expected if url has multivalued query parameters ? e.g. `http://localhost:8080/NameService/Tokens?name=Bob&name=Aaron&name=Brendon`

Comment: It appears you unaccepted the shortest answer and accepted a longer one. Since this is a code golf competition, the answer with the smallest byte count should win, which in this case is Maltysen's Pyth answer.

Comment: It seems I clicked something I did not mean to while browsing this on my mobile phone. I shall correct this right away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth - <strike>22</strike> <strike>21</strike> 18 bytes

Uses the obvious method of constructing a dictionary <strike>and using `}` to check existence.</strike> Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for the error handling trick.

```
#@.dcR\=cecw\?\&zq
```

Can probably be golfed a little more. <strike>Doing explanation now.</strike> Added explanation:

```
#                 Error handling loop
 @                Implicitly print dict lookup
  .d              Dictionary constructor, takes list of pairs
   cR\=           Map split with "=" as the second arg
    c    \&       Split by "&"
     e            Last in sequence of
      c           Split
       w          Second input
       \?         By "?"
 q                Quit loop
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%40.dcR%5C%3Dcecw%5C%3F%5C%26zq&input=action%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fsub.example.com%2Fsome%2Fdir%2Ffile.php%3Faction%3Ddelete%26file%3Dtest.foo%26strict%3Dtrue&debug=1).

Comment: `#@.dcR\=cecw\?\&zq` seems to work. Not 100% this works all the time, but basically it uses try/catch to check for the dictionary containing the element.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman oh that's really smart. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>30</s> 27 bytes

```
!`(?<=^\1 .*[?&](.*)=)[^&]+
```

This is a full program that expects the key and the URL to be space-separated on STDIN, e.g.

```
action http://sub.example.com/some/dir/file.php?action=delete&file=test.foo&strict=true
```

This is essentially just a (.NET-flavoured) regex, which matches the correct value by checking that the preceding key is equal to the first string in the input (using a backreference). The only thing that's a bit odd about the regex is that .NET matches lookbehinds from right to left, which is why the "backreference" actually references a group that appears later in the pattern. The `` !` `` instructs Retina to print the actual match (if there is one) instead of the number of matches.

For those who don't regex, here is an annotated version. Read the lookbehind from the bottom up, because that's how it's processed:

```
(?<=        # A lookbehind. Everything we match in here will not be returned as part of
            # actual match. Start reading this from the corresponding parenthesis.
  ^         # Ensure we're at the beginning of the input, so that we've checked
            # against the entire input key.
  \1        # Backreference to the key to check that it's the one we've asked for.
  [ ]       # Match a space.
  .*        # Consume the rest of the URL.
  [?&]      # Match a ? or a & to ensure we've actually captured the entire key.
  (         # End of group 1.
    .+      # Match the key.
  )         # Capturing group 1. Use this to keep track of the key.
  =         # Make sure we start right after a '='
)           # Start reading the lookbehind here.
[^&]+       # Match the value, i.e. as many non-& characters as possible.
```

Comment: Very intuitive.

Comment: @BenjaminWilliams Added more detail to the explanation. (And fixed a small bug.)

Comment: @BenjaminWilliams This is not the shortest answer and shouldn't be the accepted one. (As this is [tag:code-golf].)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 64

**Edit** Saved 1 byte thx @ismael-miguel

A function with url and key as parameters.

Test running the snippet in Firefox.

```js
f=(u,k,e='')=>u.replace(RegExp(`[?&]${k}=([^&]*)`),(m,g)=>e=g)&&e

// TEST
out=x=>O.innerHTML += x+'\n';

test=[
   'https://example.com/index.php?action=delete',
   'https://this.example.com/cat/index.php?action=delete',
   'http://example.com', 
   'https://action.example.com/actionscript/action.jpg',
   'https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2'
]

test.forEach(u=>out('Url '+u+'\nValue ['+f(u,'action')+']'))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: Save 1 byte by replacing your regex with \`[?&]${k}=([^&]*)\`

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 25 bytes

```
/[?&]$^I=([^&]*)/;$_=$1
```

This reads the URL from STDIN and the key as an argument to `-i`. It also requires the `-p` switch. I've added two bytes to the count to account for `i` and `p`.

#### Example

```
$ perl 2>&- -e'/[?&]$^I=([^&]*)/;$_=$1' -piaction <<< 'http://example.com/?action=delete'
delete
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add 1 byte for the `-i` flag, since it is used to pass the 2nd part of the input.

Comment: `-i` is normally used to provide a backup extension, so it isn't a standard input method. Counting it seemed fair, and I'm not winning any prizes anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### Bash - <strike>55</strike> 53

*2 bytes saved thanks to izabera*

```
[[ $1 =~ [?\&]$2=([^&]*) ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Takes the URL as the first arg and the key to find as the second.

```
bash url.sh "https://this.example.com/cat/index.php?action=delete&foo=bar&spam=eggs" spam
```

Comment: `[?\&]$2=([^&]*)`

Answer (score 4):

## PHP 4.1, <del>43</del>36 bytes

There's no mention to do not use built-in function, so, here is my go:

```
<?=parse_str(parse_url($U,6))?0:$$P;
```

This restricts the use of the keys `U` and `P` on your URL.
You can pass the data as you please (POST, GET, COOKIE, ...), being the key `U` the url and `P` the parameter.

Thank you, [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for this shorter version!

Also, an alternative, without the previous restrictions:

```
<?=parse_str(parse_url($U,6),$A)?0:$A[$P];
```

---

Old versions:

```
<?parse_str(parse_url($U,6),$A);echo$A[$P];
```

If you are fine with not being able to use the keys `U` and `P`:

```
<?parse_str(parse_url($U,6));echo$$P;
```

Comment: That's generally considered a [standard loophole](/a/1078)

Comment: @TobySpeight There's generally saying that standard loopholes are disallowed, which isn't the case.

Comment: @TobySpeight: That link doesn't go where you think it does. (You missed the `meta.`.)

Comment: Thanks, Dennis.  I missed the edit window, so here's my replacement: "That's generally considered a [standard loophole](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078)"

Comment: @Ismael - not disallowed, just not very interesting.  Sorry.

Comment: @TobySpeight I'm aware of that. But it isn't motivating when every challenge has CJam and APL and Pyth taking the top with answers that are 10-40 bytes long for challenges that take more in a 'normal' language.

Comment: @Ismael - agreed.

Comment: There may be interesting points even when using built-in functions. Especially with such verbose language like PHP. BTW, without explicit `echo` is shorter: `<?=parse_str(parse_url($U,6),$A)?:$A[$P];` or `<?=parse_str(parse_url($U,6))?:$$P;`

Comment: @manatwork That does't work on PHP4.1, but `<?=parse_str(parse_url($U,6))?0:$$P;` works as expected. That's because the syntax `false?:default` is only available from PHP5.3 and up. But I will include your examples.

Comment: Oh. 5.3 being released 6 years ago, I tend to forget such compatibility notes.

Comment: @manatwork I had to test it 3 times to be sure before saying something crazy. When in doubt, you can try http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/, which has multiple versions from 4.4.9 (the only PHP4 version) up to the latest ones. If you think I should change the way I present the answer, feel free to do so.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry the long delay. Only now, after a very long time, I've noticed something. You shouold check this comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1078#comment5470_1078. It has 4x more upvotes that the proposed loophole. I think this may not be considered a loophole.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 87 bytes

The script takes the first url as the first argument and the key as the second.

```
 import re,sys;print re.search(r'[?|&]'+sys.argv[2]+'+=([a-z.]+)',sys.argv[1]).group(1);
```

Sample output:

```
>> runfile('test.py', args='http://sub.example.com/some/dir/file.php?action=delete&file=test.foo&strict=true file')
>> test.foo
```

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 22 bytes

```
l'?'&er"&="l*/1>s'&/0=
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l'%3F'%26er%22%26%3D%22l*%2F1%3Es'%26%2F0%3D&input=http%3A%2F%2Fsub.example.com%2Fsome%2Fdir%2Ffile.php%3Faction%3Ddelete%26file%3Dtest.foo%26strict%3Dtrue%0Aaction).

#### How it works

```
l      e# Read a line from STDIN.
'?'&er e# Replace question marks with ampersands.
"&="l* e# Place the second line from STDIN between '&' and '='.
/      e# Split the first string at occurrences of the second.
1>s    e# Discard the first chunk.
'&/0=  e# Discard everything following an ampersand.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
|smecd\=fqhcT\=zcecw\?\&"
```

Expects the input on two lines, the key followed by the URL.

### Explanation

```
                   cw\?     Split the second input (the URL) by "?"
                  e         The end (the parameter list)
                 c     \&   Split the parameter list by "&"
        f                   Filter each parameter T
            cT\=            Split by "="
           h                The first part (the key)
          q     z           Equals the first input (the search key)
  m                         Map each valid parameter d
    cd\=                    Split d by "="
   e                        The value
 s                          Print as a string
|                        "  Otherwise, if the key isn't found, print nothing
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=|smecd%5C%3DfqhcT%5C%3Dzcecw%5C%3F%5C%26%22&input=foo%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Findex.php%3Faction%3Ddel%26foo%3Dbar%26a%3Db)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 37

```
a=${2#*\?};eval "${a//&/;};echo \$$1"
```

Pass the key in the first argument and the URL in the second.

Strips everything off up to and including the first `?`, then treats the remainder as a series of assignments (RFC 1738 URLs can't contain spaces or any of the shell metacharacters, so this works).  Finally, print the requested result; by default, strings not found are assumed empty.

Limitation - any key that already exists in the environment may be 'found' when not present in the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>235</s> <s>228</s> <s>203</s> 190 bytes

Takes the URL as the first input and the key as the second.

```
b=document.createElement('a'),b.href=prompt(u={}),a=b.search;if(a!=""){t=a.substring(1).split("&");for(i=t.length;i--;){p=t[i].split("=");u[p[0]]=p[1]}}c=u[prompt()];alert(c==undefined?"":c)
```

Comment: Interesting! I would like to offer up my 156 byte solution if you are okay with that.

Comment: Go ahead, I guess.

Comment: `function p(k){var i,q=[],r=location.href.split('?')[1].split('&');for(i=0;i<r.length;i++){q=q.concat(r[i].split('='));}return(i=q.indexOf(k))>-1?q[i+1]:'';}`

Comment: The question does seem to be asking that the url be taken from the input.

Comment: I went an clarified that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - 97

```
e:["&"| end]p: func[u a][parse u[thru"?"any[copy k to"=""="copy v to e e(if k = a[return v])]]{}]
```

Ungolfed:

```
e: ["&" | end]

p: func [u a] [
    parse u [
        thru "?"
        any [
            copy k to "=" "=" copy v to e e
            (if k = a [return v])
        ]
    ]
    {}
]
```

Example usage (in Rebol console):

```
>> p "http://sub.example.com/some/dir/file.php?action=delete&file=test.foo&strict=true" "action"
== "delete"

>> p "https://example.com/index.php?action=delete" "action"
== "delete"

>> p "https://this.example.com/cat/index.php?action=delete" "action"
== "delete"

>> p "http://example.com, https://action.example.com/actionscript/action.jpg" "action"
== ""

>> p "https://action.example.com/actionscript/action.jpg" "action"                     
== ""

>> p "http://example.com" "action"                                                     
== ""

>> p "https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2" "action"
== "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 24

```
{((!)."S=&"0:*|"?"\:x)y}
```

.

```
{((!)."S=&"0:*|"?"\:x)y}["https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2";`genre]
"action"
```

#### Explanation:

The function takes two parameters, the url `x` and the key `y`

First we split the url on the `?` character.

```
k)"?"\:"https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
"https://example.com/index.php"
"genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
```

Then we take the last element using `*|` (first reverse)

```
k)*|"?"\:"https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
"genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
```

Process the string using `0:`. The LHS of `0:` is a three character string, where the first is the datatype of the key (`S` for symbol, `I` for int etc), the second is the key-value delimiter (`=` in this case) and the third is the record delimiter (`&` here).

```
k)"S=&"0:*|"?"\:"https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
genre    reaction action
"action" ,"1"     ,"2"
```

Turn this into a dictionary using `!`

```
k)(!)."S=&"0:*|"?"\:"https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2"
genre   | "action"
reaction| ,"1"
action  | ,"2"
```

Then do a lookup on this dictionary for whichever key you're looking for.

```
k)((!)."S=&"0:*|"?"\:"https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2")`genre
"action"
```

Turn it into a function using `{}` and replace the url string with `x` and the lookup key with `y`, then pass the url and key in as paramters (`func[param1;param2;...;paramN]`)

```
k){((!)."S=&"0:*|"?"\:x)y}["https://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2";`genre]
"action"
```

Comment: Please include some text explaining your code. The post is recommended for deletion since you didn't.

Comment: If you want an explanation you just have to ask. Explanations are not required, so please don't recommend a post of mine or anyone else's for deletion for this reason again

Comment: Someone else recommended it. I was a reviewer. Also, code-only answers have always been discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

## Gema: <s>44</s> 38 characters

Expects first the parameter name then the URL on separate lines.

```
\B\L*\n=@set{p;$1}
\I$p\=/[^&]+/=$1
?=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema -p '\B\L*\n=@set{p;$1};\I$p\=/[^&]+/=$1;?=' <<< $'action\nhttps://example.com/index.php?genre=action&reaction=1&action=2'
2
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 123 bytes

```
char*f(char*s,char*n){for(char*x=n;*s&&(*x||*s!='=');x=*x++==*s++?x:n);return *s=='='?(n=strstr(s++,"&"))?(*n=0)?s:s:s:"";}
```

Note: this function assumes you aren't passing a constant char to it.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 40 bytes

```
u=>q=>new URL(u).searchParams.get(q)||``
```

[Test it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyaraR)